# Searching for a code snippet a list of .R files

Tags: r, devtools

Suppose I've discovered that in my package, a small piece of code needs to be changed and I cannot recall all the file names where that code may exist.

Is there a package development tool that can identify all the files that contain the problem code given the list of files in the `R` folder?

Right now, for 14 files in the R directory I'm using

```
> c(sapply(list.files("R", full.names = TRUE), function(x){
     grep("data/", readLines(x, warn = FALSE), value = TRUE)
  }), recursive = TRUE)
#                                                      R/load-event.R 
# "    on.exit(file.remove(paste0(\"data/\", list.files(\"data\"))))"
```

But this could be time-consuming if the file list is long, and the files themselves are big.

Comment: If you use RStudio, Edit/Find in Files can be very useful when you specify the directory.

Comment: Ahh, yes.  Thanks for that.  I'm all about RStudio.  Love how much its improved over the last couple of years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for `grep`. The following command will list all files which contain the string `data/`.

```
grep -l 'data/' R/*
```

Comment: Definitely faster in the terminal, but please note that `grep` is the main function in my original code. And I'm really searching for an R command that can be run in the console.

Comment: @RichardScriven, You can execute an external command using `system` in `R`. However, I understand what you seek. Note that R is not a language designed for filesystem manipulation, and it will almost by design by clunky.